# Why does java -version return an old version?

Tags: java

OS: Windows XP

I am using `yuicompressor-2.4.2` to compress some CSS before uploading to my server.
But when I run it, the following exception appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/Bootstrap (Unsupported major.minor version 48.0)
```

So I think it's because of the JRE.
I typed in the command:

```
cmd: java -version
```

And it says:

```
java version "1.3.1_01"
```

But it should say `1.6.0_16`, since I have installed the latest version.

What should I do to make Java use the latest version instead of the old one?

Comment: Can you post the output of `echo %path%`?

Comment: You have at least 2 versions of java installed. Remove the unwanted versions. Make sure $PATH only contains your preferred version.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set the environment variable JAVA_HOME pointing to the directory where you have jdk 1.6.0

```
set JAVA_HOME=your_path_to_jdk1.6
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;.;..;%PATH%
```

That's from a command window. Also you can do it from "My PC > Properties > Advanced > Environment variables"

Comment: Thanks that worked. =)

But i still don't know how when I updated java it didn't change the version automatically :S

Comment: It might work, but I think it's a kludge. You shouldn't need to mess with the path if your system is set up correctly.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using **windows 7/10** go to command prompt and type

```
where java
```

Delete all the symbolic link shows below other than your actual installation directory.

Even if correctly added all the environment variables still sometime you can get wrong versions especially when you have multiple version installed in your system and want to switch between them.

For example : run the command

```
where java
```

then it will return something like :

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21.0.02\bin\java.exe
```

then delete

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

Make sure to restart the terminal after this.

Answer (score 14):

Go to the system32 directory C:\Windows\System32 and delete following 3 files

- java.exe
- javaw.exe
- javaws.exe

Now create a JAVA_HOME environment variable with value={root path of your jdk installation} and add the path till bin folder of your jdk in the PATH environment variable.

Open a fresh command prompt and run java -version to confirm the change

Comment: this can be also in this directory `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` you need to delete them also

Comment: I also had to uninstall java from Windows parameters > Add or remove programs

Comment: In my case there was a shortcut to originally installed Java at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java` as `javapath`. To find out from where java is being served you can use @Masood Moghini's answer below that shows a way to list all the java installations using command `where java`

Answer (score 10):

after `where java` in Command prompt
for example

```
where java
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\java.exe
```

delete `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle` folder
then close all terminals and write `java -version` in the terminal. it will show the right version
worked for me

Answer (score 9):

On Windows, the JRE installs a `java` executable in the Windows directory, which should be the first `java` in your path. This is just a wrapper that looks in the Windows Registry to find the Java home directory (should be "%SystemDrive%\Program Files\Java\jre6" for Java 6) and runs using the libraries there.

Run %SystemRoot%\system32\java -version and see what you get. If that *is* Java 6, you have entries in your path before %SystemRoot%\system32 (which really should be first). Either fix your %PATH% variable, or you'll have to be explicit whenever you want to run this version of Java.

If running that instance of `java` doesn't report Java 6, its not installed (correctly). Uninstall and try installing again.

If you are having trouble because of the PATH, it is because you or some software you installed monkeyed with it; I recommend using the default which is to have system32 first. Everything works fine if the defaults are used.

Also, %JAVA_HOME% is not used by the JRE itself *at all.* Some common Java applications like tomcat and ant honor the %JAVA_HOME% setting, so perhaps yuicompressor does too. But this is a de facto convention, not a standard.

Comment: Awesome tip!! I never thought about this at all. I had added to my path but at the end. As soon as I adjusted the orders it resolved the issue right away. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You should modify your PATH environment variable:

My PC > Right click > properties > Advanced > Environment variables

And modify "Path"

Append at the end the path to your 1.6 installation:

```
;C:\jdk1.6.xxx\bin
```

and remove the previous one if present.

Answer (score 2):

first by the following command, you should be aware of .exe file which runs when you type `java` in the command prompt

```
where java
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\java.exe
```

as you see above , cmd first reads java from

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

so go to the path above and remove java files .
then it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Add %JAVA_HOME%/bin to your PATH environment variable where JAVA_HOME is set to your JRE6u16 directory

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In `System Properties > Environment Variables > System Variables > PATH` make sure there is no other path associated with Java. To make sure, type in and check Java paths.

```
where java
```

Re-open Command Prompt and type `java -version` again. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your PATH environment variable.  It is possible that some application you have installed has put its version of the jre in front of yours in the path.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the older Java version is still on the system PATH environment variable (where the OS looks for commands) or JAVA_HOME (where yuicompressor may look for the java executable)

How those variables are changed depends on your operating system.