# Execution of Java program

Tags: path, java

After searching all over the web, I am not able to solve my problem of Java execution. When using command prompt to run my "first" Java program, I am faced with the errors of `Unsupported class version` and `Main class not found. Program will exit`.

I have 2 versions of Java on my PC, Java 6 and 7. I have set the path of the JDK 7 in path environment variables and classpath too. I know the problem: I have `javac -version` as 1.7.02 and `java version` as 1.6.02, but how to change it and fix the problem?

Please elaborate the problem in easy and understandable language!

Comment: Windows 7@mehdishahdoost

Answer (score 3):

You have to run your program with the same or higher version of java that yxou compiled it with.

So you can either compile your program with Java 6 on your PC or run it with java 7.

To run your program with java 7 just use the complete path to your java runtime environment. for instance

```
c:\jdk7\bin\jawaw.exe yourprogram
```

How to tell your system which Java version to use is explained here:
[Why does java -version returns old version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567242/java-version-returns-old-version)

Comment: Yes but the problem is he doesn't know how to change the version of his java executable. The problem is probably this: he has installed JDK 7 and Java 6 JRE and doesn't know how to change java command to use JDK 7

Comment: What iff i wand to run a program save at my desktop...i put the desktop path and compile it it workss...how to run it from there??

Comment: Tried the steps posted at the link..Not working:(((  @juergen d

Comment: if it is a jar file you can look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file

Answer (score 0):

JRE [java command] come with your JDK 1.7, and you must change your JAVA_HOME variable to your JDK 1.7 folder.for this work read this [article](http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/setting-java-home-variable-in-windows/)